# How could I add parameters 'LOCAL_C_INCLUDES' of Android.mk file to my Android studio NDK application?

Tags: android-studio, path, android-ndk

I was converting android-ndk-command-line applications to Android Studio's applications in this book.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o1mb5.png)

But I couldn't find any other code as well as 'LOCAL_C_INCLUDES' parameters in Android.mk file.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WQXyy.png)

So, I could not change directory paths. How can I add useful paths in my application?

Answer (score 1):

Android Make Examples:
https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/tree/android-mk

> So, I could not change directory paths. How can I add useful paths in my application?

You can set any variables you want in mk file, including a directory path.

```
MY_DIR_PATH := $(LOCAL_PATH)/..

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(MY_DIR_PATH)/includes
LOCAL_SRC_FILES += \
$(MY_DIR_PATH)/src/sourcefile.cpp \
$(MY_DIR_PATH)/src/core/sourcefile.c \
$(MY_DIR_PATH)/src/fs/sourcefile.cc
```

IF you are writing from scratch or converting examples from a book, I **HIGHLY** recommend using CMakeLists instead of Android.mk.  Also, don't use file globs, just add every file path by hand into these build scripts.

```
set ( TRUNK_SOURCE_DIR ../../../../Source)
set ( PLUGIN_SRC_DIR ../../../../Source/plugins)
set ( GAME_SRC_DIR ../../../Source)
```

I've used Android.mk scripts for years, and the build times are terrible.  It would take 4 minutes to rebuild with zero changes to source.  With CMake it's a couple seconds.

CMake Examples:
https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk